# Extract contents of a drop down and save it in a string array using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I extract all the contents of a drop down using Selenium Webdriver and save it a string array. Later I need the contents of this array in another step.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Selenium-webdriver supports many languages. You will need to be specific on what language you want the answer to be in.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElements(by.xpath);
```

save it as a List. then you can call it either by call list[1]  or list[2]
Please be specific with your question.